# 'echo' command in the `if` `else` statement shows nothing

Tags: shell-script, echo

In my code here everything works fine. Except the `echo=$folder` command in the `if` `else` statement ends up doing nothing!

How would I fix this?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter the path to the folder. If already in folder type 1."
read input
echo
echo
if [ $input == 1 ];then 
folder=$PWD;echo="$folder"
else
folder=$input;echo="$input"
fi
cd $folder
ls
echo
echo
echo "File Name"
read file
sudo chmod +x $file
echo
echo
echo Done
exit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utsav gave you the correct solution. The issue was that you were assigning to a variable called `echo`.

However, I'll give some further suggestions for improving your script.

At the moment, you can't choose a folder whose name is `1`. Also, the script is needlessly interactive without having to do any interaction with the user at all. If the user, for example, gave a folder name on the command line when they invoked the script, you would not have to ask for a folder name at all. Only when the user did *not* supply the name of a folder would you need to use the current working directory:

```
#!/bin/sh

folder="$1"

if [ -z "$folder" ]; then
    printf 'No folder given, using "%s"\n' "$PWD" >&2
    folder="$PWD"
fi
```

Then, why force the user to type in the name of a file in that folder at all? You can have them pick a file from a menu:

```
select file in "$folder"/*; do
    printf 'Making "%s" executable with "sudo chmod +x"\n' "$file"
    sudo chmod +x "$folder/$file"
    break
done
```

Complete script that will skip the menu if a valid file was given on the command line:

```
#!/bin/sh

folder="$1"

if [ -z "$folder" ]; then
    printf 'No folder given, using "%s"\n' "$PWD" >&2
    folder="$PWD"
elif [ -f "$folder" ]; then
    # $folder is actually a file, chmod it and we're done
    sudo chmod +x "$folder"
    exit
fi

if [ ! -d "$folder" ]; then
    printf 'No such folder: %s\n' "$folder" 2>&1
    exit 1
fi

select file in "$folder"/*; do
    printf 'Making "%s" executable with "sudo chmod +x"\n' "$file"
    sudo chmod +x "$folder/$file"
    break
done
```

If this script is called `script.sh`, then one would be able to run it in the following ways:

```
$ ./script.sh                  # asks for file in current folder
$ ./script.sh myfolder         # asks for file in "myfolder"
$ ./script.sh myfolder/myfile  # quietly chmods "myfolder/myfile"
```

Comment: Interesting you got me thinking you know how say I type `sudo` without any arguments it says  `usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user]
usage: sudo -l [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-U user] [-u user]
            [command]
usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p
            prompt] [-u user] [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]
usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p
            prompt] [-u user] file ..`

Comment: Would it be possible to add something like this? Like `--current` would use current directory. And `-d` could be used to specify a directory? Sorry if this is putting you out in any way I just want to learn more about stuff like this and you seem pretty knowledgeable.

Answer (score 3):

Replace `echo="$folder"` with `echo "$folder"`

Same for `echo="$input"`

Here echo is acting as a variable. `=` will try to assign value to it, and not run the `echo` command it self. If after `echo="$folder"` you run `echo $echo`, you will `pwd` value.

Reproducing your result;

```
/home/test$ folder="$PWD"
/home/test$ echo="$folder"
/home/test$ echo "$echo"
/home/test
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I initially didn't think to realize this. I am sort of new to shell scripting so I probably will need to work on it. I